# bzip2 compression library not found error

Tags: macos, homebrew, package-management

I get bzip2 compression library… no error when trying to install some software on a mac running osx 10.12. Some googling revealed that the headers for bzip2 should be there for the installer to recognize bzip2 and this could be achieved by installing the dev package. However, couldn't find one for osx. For example for Fedora this is bzip2-devel.

Comment: Can you tell us what it is that you're trying to install? Might make it easier for us to help.

Answer (score 2):

By default header files aren't installed to `/usr/include`.

If you run `xcode-select install` in a Terminal window this will install the Xcode command line tools and also populate the `/usr/include` folder with a bunch of header files including `bzlib.h`.

This might be what you're looking for.